# Running Kafka commands without using the .sh extension

Tags: installation, apache-kafka, zsh

I followed an online blog on `Installing Kafka on Mac`. As instructed:

1. I first downloaded the Kafka binary
2. Extracted it
3. Set the PATH pointing to `kafka_2.13-3.2.0/bin`

Post that I ran the `kafka-topics.sh` command and it worked as expected, but then when I tried to remove the `.sh` extension it threw the error:

```
zsh: command not found: kafka-topics
```

I realized that for running all the Kafka commands I need to add the `.sh` extension else it will throw the above error.

Previously when I installed Kafka using brew I didn't have to use the `.sh` extension after every command.

How can I do the same here with my current installation process?

Comment: From the viewpoint of shell, you can name the commands as you like. My guess is that - after renaming the script - you forgot to do a `rehash`, and zsh did not update its command cache. The same can happen if you create a new command in a directory which is already in your PATH. Sometimes it works, but sometimes a rehash is necessary.

Comment: I ran into this issue today using zsh on iTerm2, i had `PATH="$PATH:~/kafka_2.13-3.5.1/bin"` in my ~/.zhsrc and couldn't get it to work consistently. Output from `echo $PATH` looked consistent.

I then tried using the expanded path, and now it works fine. 
`PATH="$PATH:/Users/username/kafka_2.13-3.5.1/bin"`

Answer (score 0):

In brew's Kafka formula code [Line 41](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/kafka.rb#L41), `.sh` extension name was removed. That's why when installing Kafka with brew, you can use Kafka commands without `.sh`.

If you rename your shell scripts and remove the extension (e.g., `mv kafka-topics.sh kafka-topic`), then you can run Kafka commands without `.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

If you add Kafka's bin folder to your PATH, and ensure the shell scripts are executable, you don't need the file extensions.

If you refer to the absolute paths of the script files to run them, you do need the extension.

This is not a unique problem to ZSH